# Big Query vs Cloud SQL for audit data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Which database is better for transactional data - cloud SQL or Google Big query?

I have a requirement wherein from multiple jobs I need to load data into a single table. Which database will be better for this Google Big query or Cloud SQL?

I know that in terms of cost effectiveness cloud sql is a better choice. But are there any other pointers apart from this?

Comment: Your question lacks details. Both services store data in tables. The keys are the data structure,  how often, how much data, what types of queries need to be performed, what response time is required. etc. In general, BigQuery is used for **data lake** type of storage where the data is huge and does not change frequently/constantly (OLAP). Cloud SQL is your classic SQL database where fast insert and query of relational data is a requirement (OLTP). Your statement **multiple jobs load data into a single table** points to Cloud SQL as the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

CloudSQL is a managed database for transactional loads (OLTP). It can be tweaked to work with OLAP (analytical); but it is intended to be a transactional database.

BigQuery is for analytical data (OLAP), that's data that won't change. Think of it as data "at rest" that's not going to be changed.

If some of your transactions are not finalized (there are in-flight transactions, or your end-to-end process need some steps), you need a transactional database - like the ones from Cloud SQL.

If your data won't change, use BigQuery.